# Exibir Hint em um GRID desabilitado

Tags: delphi, grid

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma aplicação em delphi que possui um grid com duas colunas, sendo a primeira coluna a "pergunta" e a segunda coluna a "resposta". Este grid possui 8 linhas e cada linha possui um "hint", ou seja, quando posiciono o mouse sobre uma linha, é exibido um "balão" com uma breve explicação da pergunta.

Este GRID possui 3 modos: inclusão, alteração e visualização.
Quando o GRID está com modo de inclusão e alteração, ou seja, quando ele está editável, o hint aparece normalmente. Porém, quando está no modo de visualização, o grid é desabilitado (para impedir a alteração) e com isso o hint não é exibido.

Acredito que seja algo nativo do delphi, que desativa o hint sempre que o grid está desabilitado (enable = false).

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de alterar isso. Existe algum comando no delphi que faça com que o hint de cada campo seja exibido quando o grid está desabilitado?

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Você deixa o grid como Enable=False?... porque você não deixa o DBGrid como Enable=True e altera o ReadOnly dele assim o seu hint deve funcionar.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf obrigada pela resposta! Tentei fazer desta forma e o hint apareceu, porém como existem algumas opções de resposta do grid que são do tipo "lista", o usuário consegue altera-las mesmo em modo READ_ONLY. Caso tenha alguma outra ideia para manter o grid desabilitado e fazer com o que o hint seja exibido, por favor me informe. Mais uma vez: obrigada.

Comment: @tfa não tem como exibir hint em um componente desabilitado, você terá que usar outra abordagem. Qual "grid" você está usando? Stringgrid, DBGrid, etc.?

Comment: @Guybrush Estou usando DBGrid.

Comment: @tfa, além de setar a propriedade ReadOnly para true, você está fazendo DBGrid1.Options := DBGrid1.Options - [dgEditing] ?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que não haja como exibir `Hint` em componentes desabilitados.

Eu precisei de algo assim anos atras...e achei em um forum uma maneira de  contornar a situação e é bem simples.

Você ira mascara o `grid`. Coloca a seu grid dentro de um `panel`, e tamanho do `panel` você define do tamanho do `grid`. Depois você desabilita o `grid` e ativa o `panel` com o `hint` do `grid`.

Comment: Faça como está na resposta vai funcionar... se for preciso retire as bordas do `panel` para não ficar com bordas extras no `grid` o tamanho do `panel` é  o tamanho que seria seu `grid` depois defina o `grid` com `alClient`...

Comment: Se a responta de serviu marca com aceita